# TinyMCE strips out javascript when it contains HTML tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE seems to strip out Javascript in a specific case of the content. In my test, I view a page with the editor and open the editor's Source Code window to manually insert the following code:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Replacement text';
</script>
```

Then I close the Source Code window using its "Save" button.
If I then re-open the Source Code window, the code is there.
However, if I modify the code by adding an HTML tag in the quoted replacement text as part of the innerHTML assignment:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<b>Replacement text</b>';
</script>
```

close the window with "Save", then re-open it, all of the Javascript is removed and the Source Code window is empty.

I'm unsure if I need to change an initialization property to allow this to work properly or if this is a bug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE does not allow scripts by default. It is intentional, since using third-party scripts in the editor content may entail serious security issues. The possibility of cross-site scripting attacks is very dangerous.

You can allow `<script>` tags in TinyMCE via [`extended_valid_elements`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements). But it's important to note that even if scripts are not removed from TinyMCE content, the editor would not allow them to actually run.

Thus, you can add scripts to content, but they would not start in the editor itself. Only somewhere outside it. For example, if the document is saved and opened as a webpage on your site.

Comment: I have allowed scripts per the valid elements configuration.  My question was not about allowing vs. not allowing scripts, but a particular case where TinyMCE correctly allows Javascript to be included per my configuration, but strips it only when the included Javascript includes HTML tags in a literal JS string.